# Where can you buy replacement lens caps for a Canon DSLR?

Tags: canon, lens-cap

I got a second hand canon EOS 1000 and it does not have any lens caps and I was wondering where to buy some spares.

Comment: Local camera store, eBay, Amazon, Adorama, etc

Comment: Lens caps are a different case from, say, a main board or sensor assembly.

Comment: or even .... Canon... Although, it really depends on which lens you have. The lens cap has to fit the lens, after all. Different lenses have different filter rings on the front, which dictates which lens caps will actually fit it...

Comment: Lens caps aren't particular to the _camera_, they're particular to the lens attached to the camera. What lens(es) do you have?

Comment: Have you searched *any* online shopping site?  Bags full of caps can be purchased cheap from China.  You can also purchase [transparent caps](https://www.google.com/search?q=uv+filter).

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to get a lens cap from any local camera store, or easily buy one online.

For the majority of lenses, the only thing you need to know is the diameter in millimeters of the filter thread. This would be marked with an "ø", i.e. "ø52" would indicate a 52mm filter thread, and then you just need a 52mm lens cap. It doesn't need to be a Canon lens cap.

The only exception (as far as I know) is ultra wide angle and fisheye lenses with a protruding front element (the glass extends beyond the lens barrel) - but I find it unlikely that a 2nd hand EOS 1000 would be fitted with such a lens.

Comment: What if there's no lens and OP wants a body cap?

Comment: It does say "lens cap" in the question.

Comment: But your comments made me realize that it was not entirely clear what I meant, so I have reworded slightly.

Comment: Camera bodies don't use lens caps, but the question makes no mention of lenses. So maybe OP wants a lens cap for some unmentioned lens. But why mention the body and omit the lens? Or maybe OP wants a body cap, despite writing lens cap. Then it would make sense to include details about the body, while omitting the (maybe attached) lens. Either way, they're both easy to obtain.